# How to filter and validate user input in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-filter

on my website I have a comment section. I want to filter and validate the input before I store it in my database. If there are any invalid chars in the input the user gets the notice that his input is invalid.

My question, which chars are not allowed? e.g. I want to avoid sql injections

Tags are not allowed. How do I check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Zend_Db and parameterised queries (i.e.: `$adapter->insert($tableName, array('param' => 'value'))`) then it will automagically escape everything for you.

If however you want to further validate the user input, have a look at [`Zend_Validate`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html) and [`Zend_Filter`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.html)

Also, if by "tags" you mean HTML tags, I wouldn't do anything to those on input but do make sure you properly escape / strip them on output (have a look at [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars))

If you want to display an error message if the input contains HTML tags, and assuming `$comment` is the comment body, you could try:

```
if(strip_tags($comment) !== $comment) {
    // It seems it contained some html tags
}
```

Comment: thanks, I escape things on output already. but why should I allow the user to input html tags. I want an error message to be displayed that the input is invalid

Comment: altered the answer with an example on how to show an error message if it contains html tags. I'm not sure what the context of the comment is, but it's generally harmless to allow but escape html tags. For example, if you were running a website about web development, maybe the commenter will include HTML tags as an example.